# Eslint import/no-unresolved ignore pattern for files starting with #

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb

If I put this to my .eslintrc.js file I expect it to ignore only imports starting with #, but instead it turns off the rule for everything.
How can I turn off no-resolved only for files starting with #, as an example `require('#testmodule');`

```
  rules: {
    'import/no-unresolved': [2, { ignore: ['^#.+$'] }],
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

afaik the ignore pattern always starts at the begin of the line.

so your pattern looks for lines starting with #, e.g.: `#require('testmodule');`

but more importantly, you used `ignore` which expects a boolean and as `['^#.+$']` evals to `true` the rule simply gets ignored as you've noticed.

using this (or something adapted if you want to use mjs imports) should work:

```js
rules: {
  'import/no-unresolved': [2, { ignorePattern: ['require\(#.+$\)'] }],
},
```